# error en levantamiento de google cloud plataform con java 8 y tomcat

Tags: java, java-8, google-cloud-platform

tengo una aplicacion en java 8 que se esta conectando a un bucket con google storage, se descargan las dependecias bien pero me arroja error al ejecutar la aplicacion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]